# Unable to configure ckfinder with ckeditor

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor, ckfinder

I am trying to integrate ckfinder with ckeditor. Everything is OK, except one. when I try to upload the image, I get this error (Please check image)

[image: Unable to configure ckfinder with ckeditor]

It says
"The file browser is disabled for security reasons. Please contact your system administrator and check the CKFinder configuration file"

Anyone who can help me? Please.

Comment: sometimes relogin will resolve the issue and check this first if you not seen this error before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look in the `ckFinder config` file, you will see a function like this:

```
function CheckAuthentication()
{

    return false;
}
```

By default `CheckAuthentication()` it is disabled for security reason, because it would allow anyone to upload files to your server.

For testing purposes you can return `true` but the point is that you implement some logic to only authorize autenticated user.

```
function CheckAuthentication()
{
    //put some logic here

    return isset($_SESSION['IsAuthorized']) && $_SESSION['IsAuthorized'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You solved my problem... I was searching for this, since 2 days,, But, couldn't find the exact solution.
Thanks again...

Comment: Yup, That's it! 
you would expect something like that to be a part of the installation guide ...

Comment: @meda, bro could you please take a look at my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45340568/how-to-change-image-save-location-in-ckeditor-drupal-7 ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to force the authentication method using a function that always returns true, using the following code in your config file.

Your Script (for codeigniter):

```
if(login()){
   set_cookie('ckf_role','admin',2592000*10); // 10 month
}
```

Top:

```
        $config['authentication'] = function() {
            return true;
        };
```

Middle:

```
    session_start();
    $config['roleSessionVar'] = 'CKFinder_UserRole';
    $_SESSION['CKFinder_UserRole'] = !empty($_COOKIE['ckf_role']) ? strtolower($_COOKIE['ckf_role']) : "guest";

    $config['accessControl'][] = array(
    'role'                => 'guest',
    'resourceType'        => '*',
    'folder'              => '/',
    'FOLDER_VIEW'         => false,
    'FOLDER_CREATE'       => false,
    'FOLDER_RENAME'       => false,
    'FOLDER_DELETE'       => false,
    'FILE_VIEW'           => false,
    'FILE_UPLOAD'         => false,
    'FILE_RENAME'         => false,
    'FILE_DELETE'         => false,
    'IMAGE_RESIZE'        => false,
    'IMAGE_RESIZE_CUSTOM' => false
    );

   $config['accessControl'][] = array(
    'role'                => 'admin',
    'resourceType'        => '*',
    'folder'              => '/',
    'FOLDER_VIEW'         => true,
    'FOLDER_CREATE'       => true,
    'FOLDER_RENAME'       => true,
    'FOLDER_DELETE'       => true,
    'FILE_VIEW'           => true,
    'FILE_UPLOAD'         => true,
    'FILE_RENAME'         => true,
    'FILE_DELETE'         => true,
    'IMAGE_RESIZE'        => true,
    'IMAGE_RESIZE_CUSTOM' => true
    );
```