# How to change image save location in CKeditor Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-7, ckeditor, ckfinder

I use ckeditor module for my project. 
 In ckfinder folder > config.php, 
the default image saved folder is ...

```
'baseUrl'      => '/ckfinder/userfiles/',
```

My project folder path is...

```
MAMP > htdocs > drupal > sites > all > themes > bootstrap > images
```

When I upload the image, ckfinder image folder create the location in  ...

```
MAMP > htdocs > ckfinder
```

So, the level of drupal theme folder and ckfinder folder is the same.. I don't want to be like this. 
I want to create the htdocs folder inside the theme folder. (**drupal > sites > all > themes > bootstrap > images > ckfinder folder**).

How can I do this ? Please help me...

Comment: try following this https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/add-ckfinder-to-ckeditor-for-image-file-management/

Comment: Which version of CKFinder do you use?

Comment: @zaak, 7.x-1.18 bro

Comment: Have you tried to set it up in admin panel? 
Configuration => Content authoring => CKEditor => Choose a profile and click on [Edit] => Section File browser settings => CKFinder settings area (Path to uploaded files and Absolute path to uploaded files).

Comment: No bro. But, that is only for uploading the images process, isn't it? I would like to change the location of Save folder bro.